# Multiple Select against one CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a CTE query filtering a table Student

```
  Student

   (
    StudentId PK,
    FirstName ,
    LastName,
    GenderId,
    ExperienceId,
    NationalityId,
    CityId
  )
```

Based on a lot filters (multiple cities, gender, multiple experiences (1, 2, 3), multiple nationalites), I create a CTE by using dynamic sql and joining the student table with a user defined tables (`CityTable, NationalityTable,...`)

After that I have to retrieve the count of student by each filter like

```
CityId City Count

NationalityId Nationality Count
```

Same thing the other filter.

Can I do something like

```
  ;With CTE(
         Select
         FROM Student
         Inner JOIN ...
         INNER JOIN ....)
  SELECT CityId,City,Count(studentId)
  FROm CTE
  GROUP BY CityId,City

  SELECT GenderId,Gender,Count
  FROM CTE
  GROUP BY  GenderId,Gender
```

I want to something like what LinkedIn is doing with search(people search,job search)

http://www.linkedin.com/search/fpsearch?type=people&keywords=sales+manager&pplSearchOrigin=GLHD&pageKey=member-home

It's so fast and do the same thing.

Comment: NO. A CTE is valid only **for the next (single) statement**. If you need to "preserve" the data, you need to put it into a e.g. table variable or temp table.

Comment: That's what i'm already doing.The pb is that i filter the table to only show at the end only 20 rows in a datagrid(top 21 )+the group by.it's slow with multiple joins.

Answer (score 35):

You can not use multiple select but you can use more than one CTE like this.

```
WITH CTEA
AS
(
SELECT 'Coulmn1' A,'Coulmn2' B
),
CETB
AS
(
SELECT 'CoulmnX' X,'CoulmnY' Y
)

SELECT * FROM CTEA, CETB
```

For getting count use RowNumber and CTE some think like this.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY COLUMN NAME )AS RowNumber,
Count(1) OVER() AS TotalRecordsFound
```

Please let me know if you need more information on this.

Sample for your reference.

```
With CTE AS (
         Select StudentId, S.CityId, S.GenderId
         FROM Student S
         Inner JOIN CITY C
         ON S.CityId = C.CityId
         INNER JOIN GENDER G
         ON S.GenderId = G.GenderId)
,
GENDER
AS
(
  SELECT GenderId
  FROM CTE
  GROUP BY  GenderId
  )


SELECT * FROM GENDER, CTE
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: OKi.the result of your code show the same rows number for the cte and the group by.I want to separate them.

Comment: Can you do something like this in a `VIEW`? I tried to and got a syntax error. I think you are limited to only one CTE per view.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I'm using a recursive CTE and I'm using ROW_NUMBER to allow me to skip a specified number of rows and take a subset of that.

Answer (score 15):

It is not possible to get multiple result sets from a single CTE.
You can however use a table variable to cache some of the information and use it later instead of issuing the same complex query multiple times:

```
declare @relevantStudent table (StudentID int);

insert into @relevantStudent
select s.StudentID from Students s
join ...
where ...

-- now issue the multiple queries

select s.GenderID, count(*)
from student s
join @relevantStudent r on r.StudentID = s.StudentID
group by s.GenderID

select s.CityID, count(*)
from student s
join @relevantStudent r on r.StudentID = s.StudentID
group by s.CityID
```

The trick is to store only the minimum required information in the table variable.
As with any query whether this will actually improve performance vs. issuing the queries independently depends on many things (how big the table variable data set is, how complex is the query used to populate it and how complex are the subsequent joins/subselects against the table variable, etc.).

Answer (score 13):

Do a `UNION ALL` to do multiple `SELECT` and concatenate the results together into one table.

```
  ;WITH CTE AS(
         SELECT
         FROM Student
         INNER JOIN ...
         INNER JOIN ....)
  SELECT CityId,City,Count(studentId),NULL,NULL
         FROM CTE
         GROUP BY CityId,City
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL,GenderId,Gender,Count
         FROM CTE
         GROUP BY GenderId,Gender
```

Note: The `NULL` values above just allow the two results to have matching columns, so the results can be concatenated.

Comment: When a table variable or multiple CTEs are not an option, a `UNION` with `NULLs` can be a nice way to combine two queries into one recordset.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is a very old question, but here's a solution I just used. I have a stored procedure that returns a PAGE of search results, and I also need it to return the total count matching the query parameters.

```
WITH results AS (...complicated foo here...)

SELECT results.*,
    CASE 
      WHEN @page=0 THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM results)
      ELSE -1
    END AS totalCount 
FROM results
ORDER BY bar
OFFSET @page * @pageSize ROWS FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

With this approach, there's a small "hit" on the first results page to get the count, and for the remaining pages, I pass back "-1" to avoid the hit (I assume the number of results won't change during the user session). Even though totalCount is returned for every row of the first page of results, it's only computed once.

My CTE is doing a bunch of filtering based on stored procedure arguments, so I couldn't just move it to a view and query it twice. This approach allows avoid having to duplicate the CTE's logic just to get a count.